# How to get timestamp in Azure runbook workflow

Tags: azure, workflow, azure-runbook

I am trying to get a timestamp when I do write-output lines. I have tries several things, and ending with:

```
filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"}
Write-Output "JOB START BEFORE INLINESCRIPT" | timestamp
```

But this gives me the error:

```
The 'timestamp' activity is not supported in a workflow pipeline
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your code in an [InlineScript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-powershell-workflow#inlinescript) block, like below:

```
workflow MyFirstRunbook-Workflow
{   
   INLINESCRIPT{
    write-output "hello world"
    filter timestamp {"$(Get-Date -Format G): $_"}
    write-output "JOB START BEFORE INLINESCRIPT" | timestamp
   }    
}
```

**Test result:**

[image]